# Problems with visibility of edit/save buttons for table rows (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to build a table with inputs for a budget tracking app. I'm having some trouble with the JS. Essentially I want the user to be able to add, edit and save rows.

I want only the save or edit button to be visible at one time. This works after editing and saving a row, but by default it shows all buttons. Also after editing a row the buttons are no longer in line but rather stacked on top of each other.

Any help would be really appreciated. This is my first time using JS.

**My Code**

```html
<div>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="five">
    <h1>Transactions</h1>
    <div class="txlist">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1500">
        <thead>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="txlist" id="data_table">
          <tr id="addtx">
            <td><input type="date" id="new_date" placeholder="Date"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_account" placeholder="Account"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_category" placeholder="Category"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="add_row();">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="nonew()">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row1">
            <td id="date_row1">24.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row1">Credit Card</td>
            <td id="category_row1">Expense: Restaurants</td>
            <td id="amount_row1">- $32.45</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('1')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row2">
            <td id="date_row2">24.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row2">Cash</td>
            <td id="category_row2">Transfer: Credit Card</td>
            <td id="amount_row2">+ $250.00</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('2')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row3">
            <td id="date_row3">24.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row3">Credit Card</td>
            <td id="category_row3">Transfer: Cash</td>
            <td id="amount_row3">- $250.00</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('3')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row4">
            <td id="date_row4">24.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row4">Credit Card</td>
            <td id="category_row4">Expense: Clothing</td>
            <td id="amount_row4">- $84.95</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button4" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('4')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button4" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('4')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('4')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row5">
            <td id="date_row5">23.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row5">Cash</td>
            <td id="category_row5">Expense: Groceries</td>
            <td id="amount_row5">- $25.23</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button5" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('5')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button5" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('5')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('5')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr  id="row6">
            <td id="date_row6">23.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row6">Credit Card</td>
            <td id="category_row6">Income: Salary</td>
            <td id="amount_row6">+ $2500.00</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button6" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('6')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button6" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('6')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('6')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr  id="row7">
            <td id="date_row7">23.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row7">Checking Account</td>
            <td id="category_row7">Transfer: Savings Account</td>
            <td id="amount_row7">- $500.00</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button7" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('7')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button7" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('7')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('7')">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row8">
            <td id="date_row8">22.08.2020</td>
            <td id="account_row8">Savings Account</td>
            <td id="category_row8">Transfer: Checking Account</td>
            <td id="amount_row8">+ $500.00</td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="edit_button8" value="Edit" class="edt" onclick="edit_row('8')">
              <input type="button" id="save_button8" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('8')">
              <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('8')">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var date=document.getElementById("date_row"+no);
 var account=document.getElementById("account_row"+no);
 var category=document.getElementById("category_row"+no);
 var amount=document.getElementById("amount_row"+no);

 var date_data=date.innerHTML;
 var account_data=account.innerHTML;
 var category_data=category.innerHTML;
 var amount_data=amount.innerHTML;

 date.innerHTML="<input type='date' id='date_date"+no+"' value='"+date_data+"'>";    //Should input type here be date?
 account.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='account_text"+no+"' value='"+account_data+"'>";
 category.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='category_text"+no+"' value='"+category_data+"'>";
 amount.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='amount_text"+no+"' value='"+amount_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var date_val=document.getElementById("date_date"+no).value;
 var account_val=document.getElementById("account_text"+no).value;
 var category_val=document.getElementById("category_text"+no).value;
 var amount_val=document.getElementById("amount_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("date_row"+no).innerHTML=date_val;
 document.getElementById("account_row"+no).innerHTML=account_val;
 document.getElementById("category_row"+no).innerHTML=category_val;
 document.getElementById("amount_row"+no).innerHTML=amount_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_date=document.getElementById("new_date").value;
 var new_account=document.getElementById("new_account").value;
 var new_category=document.getElementById("new_category").value;
 var new_amount=document.getElementById("new_amount").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='date_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_date+"</td><td id='account_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_account+"</td><td id='category_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_category+"</td><td id='amount_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_amount+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_date").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_account").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_category").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_amount").value="";
}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo - table cells in a `thead` section should be `<th>` not `<td>`

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, `thead` can have multiple lines, but that doesn't mean you have to use `td` instead.  One of the reasons for `th` tags is that they are easy to style separately from `td` tags on the same table.  And, of course, the OP does have `th` tags defined (just not in a complete `thead` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are better ways to achieve this, but all the same, your issue is that when saving and editing you are changing the button's style.display attribute to

```
document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
```

you need to retain

```
document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="inline-block";
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That fixed the buttons being stacked. Any idea how to only show edit or save when the page first loads?

Comment: You can use style.display = "none" to hide what you don't want to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

The markup you shared is broken. I see 2 opening `<table>` tags and 3 closing `</table>` tags.
Can you share a correct markup or minimal working code?

Comment: You're right I did have one closing tag too many. I took out the last one as it wasn't needed.